# How can I check if the user changes the form

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I am using Asp.Net and C# with several forms in different `.aspx` files that the user should fill.

After the user saves the form, it should stay filled in order to give the opportunity to the user to make some changes if he desires.

I would like to allow users to make changes by clicking the Save button, but if the case(form) is already saved, I would like to overwrite them on the same corresponding case in the DB.

However, what is the best way to check if the user makes these changes?

1. Should I compare the current values with the stored values in the database?
2. Should I take into consideration the TextChanged action of each textbox ?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Please change your title with yout specific problem. Read [faq] and [ask]

Comment: I don't quite get it. Do you want to enable the user to store multiple forms temporarily without saving it to database and lock the forms after he commits all?

Comment: I was thinking to overwrite the form in my database using UPDATE statement if the form is already saved(I have a unique id). However, how could I achieve to store a form temporarily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing data that you have with database data is one way of doing it.

Another way of doing is to use attributes [How to: Set HTML Attributes for Controls in ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a9d6h4f%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

so in your code you will do something like:

```
myTextBox.Text = "ABC";
myTextBox.Attributes.Add("myTextBoxOriginalText", myTextBox.Text);
```

Now when you get data back from the client you can check attribute value with new values

```
if (myTextBox.Attributes["myTextBoxOriginalText"] != myTextBox.Text)
{
  // Do some work
}
```

Using attributes you can check for changes on the client side using JavaScript since you have original and new value and send additional flag to the server if there are some changes.